# Gif src with base64 coding after it?

Tags: html, css, base64

I have been asked to work on a web site and I see links like this. Has anyone seen anything like this before? I am wondering what the base64 code is for:

```
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the hash is the actual contents of the gif encoded with base64

[example](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html)

Comment: Ahh okay. So you mean to say that I could use this technique and not need to have an image downloaded?

Comment: @Mariko exactly ... this way you can display a `gif` file that doesn't exists as a file

Comment: Thanks very much. This is something I've never seen before.

Comment: this technique is convenient for some people that fetch the images from the database

Comment: @Mariko - before sticking with this technique I suggest you read some disadvantages just to make sure it will work in your implementation for sure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

Actually data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw== - specifically this code is a PLACEHOLDER gif , if you loaded your image either failed to load or cannot be found...